# In swift, how to convert a struct used for dependency injection, and apply it for CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, type-conversion, persistence

I have applied dependency injection in my app, and it works very well.
I created an instance of a struct Personne:

```
struct Personne {let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    var nom: String = ""
    var prenom: String = ""
    var age: Int = 18
    var email: String = ""
    var motDePass: String = ""
    var genre: Genre = .Femme
   enum Genre {
    case Homme, Femme, Autre}
   //etc ...
}
```

and i put his accessibility from this class:

```
class PersonneController {
    var shared = Personne()
}
```

I inject it from app delegate like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
        var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        // injection de dépendance : variable personne
        if let AnimationPageDeDemarrageController = window?.rootViewController as? AnimationPageDeDemarrageController {
            AnimationPageDeDemarrageController.personne = PersonneController() }
        return true
    }
```

and in each view controller, i put an instance that retrieve it like this:

```
var personne = PersonneController()
```

So every where in my app i can use the instance from Personne.
but now i have to use core data, and i have 50 view controllers.

i need your help, your advice to put persistence in my app .Is it possible to convert the struct of person in an NSManagedObject?
I already create an instance in appDelegate like this:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myFirstApp")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer
    }
    
    static var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
```

How could i convert the unique instance of Personne for CoreData, and manipulate it in the different view controller ?
Is it going to be very complicated?
Am I going to remake everything ?

Comment: I don't understand, it looks like PersonneController is a singleton but is it really that? Does every view controller share the same instance or have their own? And why are you using PersonneController() instead of PersonneController.shared?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes every controller share the same instance of Personne, and each segue transmits it. PersonneController()  is for having one instance . and the injection begins from the app delegate
here is the link of what i applied: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-share-state-between-swift-view-controllers--cms-28474
i need this unique instance from everywhere in the app. and the injection have to begin from appDelegate. with class PersonneController i have no bugs, because when i applied th singletton pattern, it made a lot of bugs and miscalculations

Comment: Are you only going to store one instance of Personne in Core Data, if so then you need to replace your current struct with the corresponding Core Data class and of course add some more functionality for loading and saving it. But if you need to work with multiple Personne objects then this is not a way forward.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes i will have only the instance of Personne to store in CoreData and nothing else. When you say more functionality, you are talking about what ? creating context and saving it in the NSPersistantModel? if yes, i need to say that my problem actually is about the convertion of the instance of Personne. I have some Enum in it. and i don't kwow how to convert it. you can see that in my question upper.

Comment: For enums the easiest solution is to use [raw values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID149) with your enum like Int or String and then store that value in Core Data to represent the enum case.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson like this:
```
enum CompassPoint: String {
    case north, south, east, west
}

var direction: CompassPoint = CompassPoint(rawValue: "north")!
"""

Comment: What I meant was that you can't do `var shared = Personne()` anymore, you need to fetch the object from Core Data instead or create it if it doesn't exist yet. And since Personne now will be a class I don't think you need PersonneController anymore.

Comment: Yes and then you have a String attribute in your Core Data entity where "north" etc is stored

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i will try. i think that i am going to spend some nights on it. thank you for your advices. They help me.